# Get the counter value at the end of all thread execution in jmeter

Tags: jmeter

It might be a simple thing but not getting the required end result,
I have an endpoint which will redirect to /a route OR /b route, I need to get the final count that how many times it redirected to /a and /b.
I have fetched the redirected URL using regex and field to check(URL) from there got the value of a OR b, based on the result created two if controller with counter, if a or b increase the counter.. now comes the tricky part, I want after 1000 users hit that url, then at the end it should get the counter values like split for a is 300 for b it is 700.. as of now I[image] am getting result but for every thread execution-
Split a 1
Split a 2
Split b 1
…..
…. So on

Comment: if there is a better way to achieve this please do share. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[JMeter Variables are local to the threads](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html) so there is "no way to achieve this".

If you want to count occurrences of redirections to this or that endpoint I would rather suggest amending the label of your HTTP Request sampler and append what the Regular Expression Extractor gives you as the postfix using [JSR223 PostProcessor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PostProcessor) and the following sample code:

```
prev.setSampleLabel(prev.getSampleLabel() + ' ' + vars.get('what_regular_expression_extractor_gives_you'))
```

Once done you can count the occurrences by a Listener like [Aggregate Report](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Aggregate_Report)

Demo:

[image]

Also be informed that [starting from JMeter 3.1 it's recommended to use JSR223 Test Elements and Groovy language for scripting](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#bsh_scripting) so consider migrating. More information: [Beanshell vs. JSR223 vs. Java For JMeter: Complete Showdown](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/beanshell-vs-jsr223-vs-jmeter)